# How to bind-pack list of null terminated strings?

Tags: string, binary

According to the bindat spec [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Bindat-Spec.html), there are two specs to pack
strings. They are `str` and `strz`. Both are for a fixed length
string.

Now, suppose I want to pack `("some" "list" "of" "string)`, I should
do this:

```lisp
(bindat-pack
 '((elem0 strz 5)
   (elem1 strz 5)
   (elem2 strz 3)
   (elem3 strz 7))
 '((elem0 . "some")
   (elem1 . "list")
   (elem2 . "of")
   (elem3 . "string")))
```

But that is so inflexible for several reasons:

1. I have to put name and length manually.
2. `strz` need to know size of the string before hand instead of just
   calculate the length of given string.

There are `vec` and `repeat` in the bindat spec but both are the same,
both need length of the list before hand.

So far, I've come up with this:

```lisp
(require 'seq)
(require 'bindat)

(defun make-strz-spec (name value)
  (let ((value (cond ((stringp value) value)
                     ((symbolp value) (symbol-name value))
                     (t (error "%s is neither string nor a symbol" value))))
        (sym (make-symbol name)))
    `((,sym strz ,(+ 1 (string-bytes value)))
      (,sym . ,value))))

(defun make-strz-spec-list (string-list)
  (seq-map-indexed
   (lambda (str idx)
     (let ((name (concat "elem-" (number-to-string idx))))
       (make-strz-spec name str)))
   string-list))

(defun bindat-pack-list-of-string (string-list)
  (let ((spec-pair (make-strz-spec-list string-list)))
    (bindat-pack
     (mapcar (lambda (elem) (nth 0 elem)) spec-pair)
     (mapcar (lambda (elem) (nth 1 elem)) spec-pair))))

;; this
(bindat-pack-list-of-string '("some" "list" "of" "string"))
```

But, that introduces more functions globally with very specific
purpose. I don't want to pollute programming environment just for
this.

Since I am still new with emacs-lisp and lisp in general. I am sure
there's a better way than mine.

So, back to my main question, how can I bind-pack list of null
terminated string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function or macro that returns what you need isn't necessarly hard, long, or specially heavy; neither needs little more than a few primitives. For example:

```lisp
(defun pack-string-list (l)
  (setq l (reverse l))
  (let* (sym spec strc)
    (dotimes (i (length l))
      (setq sym (make-symbol (concat "elem"
                                     (number-to-string i))))
      (push (cons sym (list 'strz 
                            (+ 1 (string-bytes (nth i l))))) 
            spec)
      (push (cons sym (nth i l)) strc))
    (bindat-pack spec strc)))
```

I don't know `bindat` package beyond this scope, but something easy-to-follow like this function looks like a fair trade-off to me if your concerns, whose meaning I don't understand, are right. Also probably such function could be written more idiomatically or simplified.